# Find out if WebView has been destroyed

Tags: android

If I call `WebView.destroy()` and I have a reference to that view somewhere else in my code, is there a way to detect that the webView has been destroyed?  I was looking for something like `WebView.isDestroyed()`.

As a hack right now I have added the following in my code.  I have no idea how reliable or useful checking the context will be.  Does destroy set the context to null, I quickly glanced at the source code for WebView.java in android, but it was a little over my head, almost all calls just got forwarded to mProvider, I didn't want to dig much longer if StackOverflow has my answer.

```
public void isWebViewDestroyed(WebView v)
{
    return v.getContext() == null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(webView==null)
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: Don't actually set it to null, just call destroy, the WebView object itself still exists, although I should probably just set it to null then I wouldn't have to worry about testing if it is destroyed or not.

Comment: If you are sure you are not going to reuse it then it is a good idea to set to null.

Comment: Yea, I know that.  Sometimes I make dumb decisions, but I never realize until after I post on StackOverflow, lol.